# Why will my Windows executable not run when I build it from this makefile?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, mingw

In purpose of automatic tests for the project i need to convert visual studio vcxproj file to a makefile for it to be later compiled. 
I have installed mingw on my laptop. Later took the most simple console application and created makefile for it.

```
EXECUTABLE=..\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe

CC=gcc
LINK=gcc
LDFLAGS=-lgdi32

src = $(wildcard *.cpp)
obj = $(src:.cpp=.o)

all: myprog


myprog: ConsoleApplication3.cpp
    $(CC) -c ConsoleApplication3.cpp  -o $(EXECUTABLE) 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    del $(obj) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

It compiles and builds when i run the "make" utility but when i try to run it has an error:

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows you are running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need x86 or x64 version of the program."

How can i edit makefile to make it work?

Comment: Did you consider the opposite direction? I.e. convert makefile to vcxproj?

Comment: Did you consider to generate both from a third source? CMAKE comes to mind.

Comment: I need to create a new makefile from an existing vcxproj.

Comment: Why do you run `make utility` ? **utility** does not seem to be a target. I think you should just run `make all`. Also, try to create a simple `Hello World` main and to build it from command line with `gcc main.c -o main.exe`. If you cannot run main.exe, then you don't have the correct toolchain installed. PS: Consider using MinGW-w64 instead of MinGW. You can find a pre-compiled build of MinGW-w64 [here](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

Comment: Oh and another issue that I see : With the `-c` option you tell **gcc** not to link the application, so basically `ConsoleApplication3.exe` is the output from the compiler, not the linker, so it cannot be executed. If you don't have multiple files to build, just remove the `-c` option and it should work better.

Comment: Yes , exactly that was that mistake. Thank you very much.